# Can DLRS update an Aggregate Result Field where the Field to Aggregate is a formula field on the same record and there's been no edit to the record?

Tags: dlrs

Can DLRS update an Aggregate Result Field that's a picklist or a text field where the Field to Aggregate is a formula field and the DLRS Parent and Child Objects are the same custom object and the change to the Field to Aggregate formula field is due to a change on a a couple of different parent objects and there's been no other edit to the record that the DLRS is working on?

I'm attempting to set up automation to change a picklist value on records in order to meet and not meet the criteria in sharing rules for this custom object. The edits happen on parent records which change a value in a formula field. Sharing Rules can't use formula fields in their criteria so I want DLRS to update the picklist field on the same record when the value in the formula value changes. But because there's no edit happening to this child record it is not triggering.

I'm using the Aggregate Operation: First, Relationship Field: ID, Calculation Mode: Realtime and Calculation Sharing Mode: System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the change to the Field to Aggregate formula field is due to a change on a a couple of different parent objects and there's been no other edit to the record that the DLRS is working on

No. Nothing can do that in real time because there's no trigger event on the rolled-up record.

You would need to either:

- Create a triggerable event by using automation on the objects that are actually edited to touch the object DLRS is rolling up, causing DLRS's triggers to run.
- Run your rollup in scheduled mode rather than real time mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few working options now - from recent DLRS and Flow Updates -

1. You can use a Record Triggered flow and the ISCHANGED() condition on your formula field to trigger the DLRS. Just set your DLRS calculation mode to "Process Builder" and add the "Calculates a Rollup" apex action to the flow. Reference: [DLRS with Record Triggered Flows](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dlrs-record-triggered-flows-salesforce-tristan-nohrer/)
2. You could create a NEW text field set to Read Only. Don't add it to the page layout or Lightning Record page. Create a Record Triggered flow that updates the new text field behind the scenes for your related records. Use this new text field as your aggregate and add to your relationship criteria as needed.